# How to output numbers

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a program that requests the user enter as many floating points as they wish to. I need to output these values on the console and apply the following return values as well: I need to find the sum of the numbers

- The average of the numbers
- The lowest value number
- The highest value number

I can't figure out how to get an output

Here is my current code:

```
bool charactersFound = false;
List<float> allNumbers = new List<float>();
while (charactersFound == false)
{
    while (charactersFound == false)
    {
        String textEntered = Console.ReadLine();
        if (textEntered.ToUpperInvariant().Contains("STOP"))
        {
            charactersFound = true;
        }
        break;
        allNumbers.Add(float.Parse(textEntered));
    }
    float max = array.Max();
    float min = array.Min();
    float total = array.Sum();
}
```

How can I output this on the console with each of the above values on separate lines?

Comment: And where is your problem? We´re not doing your job. It´s not that hard to calculate a lists average. You´d have at least some *idea* on how to achieve this. Moreover you allredy seem to have the solution, at least for min, max and sum. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: And the Question is??

Comment: You don't need the outer loop. You can also make it a `while (true)` because you have a `break` in the middle. Average is `sum` divided by the number of entries. Don't forget to check that you have at least one entry before computing the average.

Comment: My problem is I can't output it (also I'm learning C# cause I'm a student, not a dev)

None of the code I have on this page actually provides an output. All it's doing is compiling and allowing the user to enter values and stop the values.

Comment: Use `Console.WriteLine("Min={0} Max={1} Sum={2}", min, max, sum);` for output.

Comment: @Harry Why didn't you google "how to get output C#" or something? People are much happier to help you if you show some sign of having made an effort to research the question before asking it.

Comment: I've tried following code to no avail: "float[] numbers = new float[] {Console.ReadLine};"
I've also asked my companies main dev (Im only the apprentice) if he has any ideas on how he can help but have not heard back from him regarding output, and our infrastructure  lead doesnt know C#.

Comment: Move the `break` statement inside that `if`.  `break` breaks out of the loop it's in.  So what you have now will let the user enter a value then exit the loop before adding it to the list.  Then you don't need the `charactersFound` variable at all - you can just use `while (true)`.

Comment: What is this `float[] numbers = new float[] {Console.ReadLine}`? Did you just throw keywords together at random? You made no attempt to learn how to use Console.ReadLine(). You have done nothing. You just came here asking somebody to write your code for you because you refuse to try to use google.

Comment: Again, I'm still trying to learn C#. I googled a lot of different things to try and solve this, I was on the microsoft C# website for around an hour trying to find a solution but couldn't crack it. I came here because I'm aware some people, don't mind helping people who are new to the language. I'd rather you weren't so intolerant to people who aren't so good at programming as yourself. I for one wouldn't wish to get so frustrated with someone trying to teach themselves an entirely new language. Please do not assume my reasons for requesting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Extract method* (`inputArray` in your case), please, do not put everything into single routine:

```
   private static float[] inputArray() {
     List<float> list = new List<float>();

     while (true) {
       string textEntered = Console.ReadLine();

       if (textEntered.ToUpperInvariant().Contains("STOP"))
         return list.ToArray();

       if (float.TryParse(textEntered, out var item))
         list.Add(item);
       else
         Console.WriteLine($"\"{textEntered}\" is not a floating point value, ignored");
     }
   } 

   ...

   float[] array = inputArray();

   //TODO: you may want to check here if array is not empty
   if (array.Length == 0)
     Console.WriteLIne("The array is empty");
   else {
     Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(", ", array)}]"); 
     Console.WriteLine($"  Max   = {array.Max()}"); 
     Console.WriteLine($"  Min   = {array.Min()}"); 
     Console.WriteLine($"  Total = {array.Sum()}");  
   }
```